# how to configure nginx to serve static site over https?

Tags: nginx, https

I have a static html site that is working normal over http, but is not working over https,
I don't know what is wrong, here is my nginx config file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    root /var/www/site.com/site;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name site.com www.site.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/site.com/site.com;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/site.com/myserver.key;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
```

}

Comment: Do you mind being more specific. Is it hung? For example,  that could be due to a firewall rule not allowing port TCP connections on port 443. Or do you see the request on the error logs, if so what does it say? BTW, did you restart the server. Or are the certs readable by nginx?

Comment: @EricFortis you were right, the problem was the firewall rule, now it's working, thanks a lot